# Printing out a function and a string doesn't work! Python

Tags: python

I have a function that basically makes a list called `main()` and I want to print out this function 10 times. For that I use a piece of code:

```
for x in range(10):
    x += 1
    print(str(x) + " - " + str(main()) + "\n")`
```

The output I want is:

```
1 - [3, 5, 10, 28, 33]
2 - [5, 12, 28, 33, 34]
```

But the output I get is:

```
[3, 5, 10, 28, 33]
1 - None
[5, 12, 28, 33, 34]
2 - None
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: You have a divide by zero error on line 23... Just kidding. We can't diagnose the problem without a [mcve].

Comment: wheres your version of `main`?

Comment: `main` is not shown but likely contains no return statement, hence the `None` values- this is guesswork of course

Comment: It is obvious,  your main() function doesn't return any value.

Comment: Stab in the dark: you `print` the list within `main` instead of `return`ing it…

Comment: yeah i figured it out thanks, my function wasn't returning anything.. it was just printing it

Answer (score 1):

You are confounding how functions work: functions should **return** a value. `print` is a function itself that writes values to the terminal. By the output you posted, we can see that you are *printing* values from inside your main function.

So you should check the sources where you are learning Python from, and find out by yourself the difference between *printing* a value and *returning* a value. Afterwards, just add a proper `return` statement inside your `main` function and it should work as you expect.

Also, as people have pointed out - it is not always that it is possible to guess what is going on if you post only part of your code. When asing questions make sure you post a minimum example of code that can be run and reproduce your problem.